# How to escape potential quotes in a variable used in a sql string to be executed?

Tags: sql

I have a sql script within which I construct and store a sql string into a variable and then execute that sql string afterwards.

Inside that sql string, I need to create a new column from a dynamic variable passed. One of the possible value of that variable contains a single quote and it causes my script to fail.

I tried several way of escaping the quotes but failed to get it working. Can any of you provide some help? Thank you very much in advance!

Simplified target sql query to be executed (which works fine):

```sql
SELECT 'Alice''s Bakery' AS name
```

After putting it into the variable as a string:

```sql
DECLARE @sSQLString nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @curName nvarchar(510)

SET @curName = 'Alice''s Bakery'

SET @sSQLString = 'SELECT ''' + @curName + ''' AS name'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQLString
```

It will fail and give error message: "SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near 'Bakery'."

Comment: Hey amazing it works!!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REPLACE to double-up the quotes.

```
DECLARE @sSQLString nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @curName nvarchar(510)

SET @curName = 'Alice''s Bakery'

SET @sSQLString = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@curName, '''', '''''') + ''' AS name'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQLString
```